# Getting output of a NodeJS script in PHP

Tags: php, node.js

I'm using a NodeJS script to do some geo calculations using the h3.js library by Uber. the concept of getting a nodejs script result back into php is new to me. I found the following example online, which I'm not following.

```
$output = [];
$arg = escapeshellcmd('some variable to pass on');
$command = 'node /var/www/hex/src/h3.js ' . $arg;
exec($command, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

This is returning the correct result, which I'm using `console.log()` for on the NodeJS side.

- I'm wondering if my method has any implications I might not be aware of
- Is this the way to go for a case like this?

Comment: What other PHP code exists in this project? Is it just this, which gets passed onto the client, or is there other stuff as well?

Comment: This would be the code of one method (h3Service.php for example) that gets the output and passes it on to my database.

Comment: They probably meant escapeshellarg, not escapeshellcmd... From manual: "Warning
escapeshellcmd() should be used on the whole command string, and it still allows the attacker to pass arbitrary number of arguments. For escaping a single argument escapeshellarg() should be used instead." https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: BTW can you explain what you mean by "the following example which I'm not following". Either that's the code of the example and then it is off-topic because of authorship of the code. Or that's your code and than the reference to an example you found is completely irrelevant and in worse case, confusing... Or maybe the word "not" should not be there?